# Is it possible to convert a float to double?

Tags: python-3.x, struct, floating-point, double

I’m working on a TXT to SPC converter, and certain values have to be stored as hex of double, but Python only works with float and `struct.unpack(‘<d’, struct.pack(‘<f’, value))`/any other unpack and pack matryoshka doll I can conceive doesn’t work because of the difference in byte size.

The SPC library unpacks said values from SPC as `<d` and converts them to float through `float()`

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be getting confused by different programming languages' naming strategies.

There's a class of data types known as "floating point numbers". Two floating-point number types defined by IEEE-754 are "binary32" and "binary64". In C and C++, those two types are exposed as the types `float` and `double`, respectively. In Python, only "binary64" is natively supported as a built-in type; it's known as `float`.

Python's `struct` module supports both binary32 and binary64, and uses C/C++'s nomenclature to refer to them. `f` specifies binary32 and `d` specifies binary64. Regardless of which you're using, the module packs from and unpacks to Python's native `float` type (which, remember, is binary64). In the case of `d` that's exact; in the case of `f` it converts the type under the hood. You don't need to fool Python into doing the conversion.

Now, I'm just going to assume you're wrong about "stored as hex of double". What I think you probably mean is "stored as double" -- namely, 64 bits in a file -- as opposed to stored as "hex of double", namely sixteen human-readable ASCII characters. That latter one just doesn't happen.

All of which is to say, if you want to store things as binary64, it's just a matter of `struct.pack('d', value)`.